# MS Access Convert Recordsource to SQL

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I have a function that generates an HTML table from an SQL query string.

I want to get the current active report's query string with all my filters and generate an HTML table from that. Then, I can include it in my Outlook email.

I am trying to create a function that does the following:

1. Opens up MS Outlook.
2. Opens an already made template.
3. Replaces a string in the template with the table generated from the currently active report.
4. Add the currently active report as a PDF attachment.

Here is my code:

```vb
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Private Sub emailSupplier_Click()
    ' Define the parameters
    Dim objOutlook As Outlook.Application
    Dim objOutlookMsg As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim objOutlookRecip As Outlook.Recipient
    Dim objOutlookAttach As Outlook.Attachment
    Dim templateExpediter As String
    Dim msgBody As String
    Dim strFind As String
    Dim strNew As String
    Dim currentReport As Report
    Dim query As String

    ' Set the params
    Set currentReport = Screen.ActiveReport
    Set query = currentReport.RecordSource
    Set templateExpediter = "D:\Templates\expediter.oft"
    ' Create the Outlook session.
    Set objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    ' Create the message.
    Set objOutlookMsg = objOutlook.CreateItemFromTemplate(templateExpediter)

    With objOutlookMsg
       ' Add the To recipient(s) to the message.
       Set objOutlookRecip = .Recipients.Add("firstmail")
       objOutlookRecip.Type = olTo

       ' Add the CC recipient(s) to the message.
       Set objOutlookRecip = .Recipients.Add("secondamail")
       objOutlookRecip.Type = olCC

       ' Set the Subject, Body, and Importance of the message.
       .BodyFormat = olFormatHTML
       .Subject = "Urgent Delivery Request - " & Date
       .Importance = olImportanceHigh 'High importance

       strFind = "{X}"
       ' Get HTML from the query for the record set
       strNew = GenHTMLTable(query)
       .HTMLBody = Replace(.HTMLBody, strFind, strNew)

       ' Resolve each Recipient's name.
       For Each objOutlookRecip In .Recipients
          objOutlookRecip.Resolve
       Next

       ' Should we display the message before sending?
       'If DisplayMsg Then
          '.Display
       'Else
          .Save
          .Display
       'End If

    End With
    Set objOutlook = Nothing

End Sub
```

My question is how can I convert my current active report recordsource or set, into an active HTML table?

Or at least get the SQL Query with filters so I can generate using the function 
`QueryToHtmlTable(Query)`.

- EDIT 2 - 
  Ok, so i got the correct SQL with filters. Now it seems this function to generate HTML from the sql is giving me an error 'item is not found in collection'

  ```
  Function GenHTMLTable(sQuery As String, Optional bInclHeader As Boolean = True) As String
      On Error GoTo Error_Handler
      Dim db As DAO.Database
      Dim qdf As DAO.QueryDef
      Dim prm As DAO.Parameter
      Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
      Dim fld As DAO.Field
      Dim sHTML As String

      Set db = CurrentDb
      Set qdf = db.QueryDefs(sQuery)

      For Each prm In qdf.Parameters
          prm = Eval(prm.Name)
      Next prm

      Set rs = qdf.OpenRecordset
      With rs
          sHTML = "<table>" & vbCrLf
          If bInclHeader = True Then
              'Build the header row if requested
              sHTML = sHTML & vbTab & "<tr>" & vbCrLf
              For Each fld In rs.Fields
                  sHTML = sHTML & vbTab & vbTab & "<th>" & fld.Name & "</th>" & vbCrLf
              Next
              sHTML = sHTML & vbTab & "</tr>" & vbCrLf
          End If
          If .RecordCount <> 0 Then
              Do While Not .EOF
                  'Build a row for each record in the recordset
                  sHTML = sHTML & vbTab & "<tr>" & vbCrLf
                  For Each fld In rs.Fields
                      sHTML = sHTML & vbTab & vbTab & "<td>" & fld.Value & "</td>" & vbCrLf
                  Next
                  sHTML = sHTML & vbTab & "</tr>" & vbCrLf
                  .MoveNext
              Loop
          End If
          sHTML = sHTML & "</table>"
      End With

      GenHTMLTable = sHTML

  Error_Handler_Exit:
      On Error Resume Next
      If Not fld Is Nothing Then Set fld = Nothing
      If Not rs Is Nothing Then
          rs.Close
          Set rs = Nothing
      End If
      If Not db Is Nothing Then Set db = Nothing
      Exit Function

  Error_Handler:
      MsgBox "The following error has occured" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & _
             "Error Number: " & Err.Number & vbCrLf & _
             "Error Source: GenHTMLTable" & vbCrLf & _
             "Error Description: " & Err.Description & _
             Switch(Erl = 0, "", Erl <> 0, vbCrLf & "Line No: " & Erl) _
             , vbOKOnly + vbCritical, "An Error has Occured!"
      Resume Error_Handler_Exit
  End Function
  ```

ANSWER

```
    Dim currentReport As Report
    Dim strSQL As String

    ' Set the params
    Set currentReport = Screen.ActiveReport
    ' Replace double qoutes with single qoutes
    strSQL = Replace(currentReport.RecordSource, ";", "") & " AND " & currentReport.filter
    strSQL = Replace(strSQL, Chr(34), "'")
    strSQL = Replace(strSQL, ")", "")
    strSQL = Replace(strSQL, "(", "")
```

Comment: There is no question. What is the issue you have?

Comment: My Question is, how can i get the recordsource of the current active report, to convert to an HTML table.

Comment: This seems like you are asking for code. Where is the attempt at the HTML?

Comment: No, i'm asking for a way to extract the current active reports' query and filters applied by the user in SQL.

Comment: Not showing revised code to extract and build SQL string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understand well your need,

After you have opened a report for preview, you would like to grab the filter you used to generate it and then mail it along with the report.

I would suggest to have a function that generate the report and then mail it

```
Function GenerateAndMailReport
    Dim strRecordSourceSample
    strRecordSourceSample = "reportQuery"
    Dim strFilterSample
    strFilterSample = "[SomeID] = 109902"
    Call DoCmd.OpenReport("reportName", acViewPreview, , strFilterSample)
    Call emailSupplier(strRecordSourceSample, strFilterSample) 'Passing the filter and record source to your mailing function
End Function
```

-EDIT-

If you already have access to your report object, then you can grab

```
currentReport.RecordSource
currentReport.Filter
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/VBA/Access-VBA/articles/report-recordsource-property-access
https://msdn.microsoft.com/VBA/Access-VBA/articles/report-filter-property-access

They will both return you strings which you can use to open a recordset

```
Dim SQL As String
Dim QRY As New ADODB.Recordset

SQL = currentReport.RecordSource & " WHERE " & currentReport.Filter
QRY.Open SQL, CurrentProject.Connection, adOpenDynamic, adLockOptimistic
While Not oQRY.EOF
HtmlLogicHere()
Wend
oQRY.Close
```

Just be carefull if you already have a WHERE clause in your recordset, the concatenating will be different.

Comment: I want to extract the actual query from the currently active report with all the currently applied filters by the user.

Comment: This solved the issue, i extracted the replaced using the recordsource and filters. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If the report Filter property is set in the OpenReport method or right click shortcut menu:

`strSQL = Replace(Reports!report.RecordSource, ";","") & " WHERE " & Reports!report.Filter`

Unfortunately, if report RecordSource is a dynamic parameterized query the parameter values will not be in the RecordSource sql, only the variable reference.

Comment: I have an open report, with filters applied by the user, and i want to extract it's SQL so i can use it in other locations

Comment: Exactly how is user applying filters? Both answers show how to extract the SQL statement.

Comment: He is applying them by right clicking in the report by mouse.

Comment: I just did a test. That method does set the report's Filter property so the suggested code should extract. Have you tried it?

Comment: This method works perfectly in getting the correct SQL. Yet i have a probmel with the code itself. I get the error "Item is not found in the collection.

Comment: Did you put your actual report name in place of 'report'?